# How can i iterate mongoose returned documents array in loop using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a `node.js(express based)` server in which i have a `function` which returns all `users`. Here is the function.

```
export async function findAllUser() {
  let users = await User.find({}).exec()
  return users
}
```

In my `node.js` applicaiton i have two `models(schema)` of `Users` and `Referrals` like this .

```js
var User = mongoose.model(
    "users",
    new Schema({
        first_name: String,
        last_name: String,
        name: String,
        email: String,
        password: String,
        roleId: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        country: String,
        token: String,
        createdAt: String,
        updatedAt: String,
        tempToken: String,
        verificationCode: String,
        fbUserId: String,
        isFbUser: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        isActive: { type: Boolean, default: true },
        isEmailVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        rememberme: Boolean,
    }, {
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
        toObject: { virtuals: true }
    })
);

User.virtual("referrals", {
    ref: "referralLinks",
    foreignField: "userId",
    localField: "_id"
});
```

```
export var ReferralLink = mongoose.model(
    "referralLinks",
    new Schema({
        referral_link: String,
        referral_code: String,
        isLink: Number,
        offer_name: String,
        offer_desc: String,
        user_email: String,
        companyId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'companies' },
        addedByAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: true },
        number_of_clicks: Number,
        referral_country: String,
        link_status: String,
        categoryId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' },
        number_of_clicks: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        createdAt: String,
        updatedAt: String,
        userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }
    })
);
```

I have my separate `api.route.js` file in which i have get all users route like this

```
router.get("/", log, getAllUsers);
```

And i my `api.controller.js` file i have `getAllUsers` like this

```
export async function getAllUsers(req, res) {
try {
    let Users = await findAllUser()
    if (Users) {
        generateResponse(true, "All Users fetched", Users, res)
    } else {
        generateResponse(false, "No Users found", null, res)
    }
 } catch (err) {
    generateResponse(false, 'Error occured, 404 not found!', err, res)
 }
}
```

And in my `api.handler.js` file i have `findAllUser` function like this

```js
export async function findAllUser() {
    let users = await User.find({}).populate("referrals").exec()
    return users
}
```

Single user can have more than one `Referrals`. But unfortunately i don't have 'Referrals' reference `_id` in `Users` document. Now, i want to get all users with their respective `Referrals`

I am getting all `users` correctly but for each user i also want to fetch all their respective `referrals`. So for that i definitely can't use `for` or `forEach` loop because of async nature of mongoose find. So what should i use instead of `for` or `forEach` loop?

My desired results

```js
 results = [
            {
                first_name : "Fahad",
                last_name : "subzwari",
                email : "fahadsubzwari@gmail.com",
                password : "***",
                referrals  : [
                    {
                        //referral object 1
                    },
                    {
                        //referral object 2 ... 
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                first_name : "Alex",
                last_name : "Hales",
                email : "alex@gmail.com",
                password : "***",
                referrals  : [
                    {
                        //referral object 1
                    },
                    {
                        //referral object 2 ... 
                    },
                    {
                        //referral object 3 ... 
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
```

Comment: You say " i don't have 'Referrals' reference _id in Users". Do referrals have a reference to the User? You will need some way to link them.

Comment: Can you add code for Users and Referrall schema? Also some example documents would be fine.

Comment: @JamesTrickey yes i have `Users` `_id ` in `Referrals`

Comment: @JamesTrickey i have updated my question please see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to access referrals from user you need to use [virtual populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals).

So your userSchema must be like this:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    roleId: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    country: String,
    token: String,
    createdAt: String,
    updatedAt: String,
    tempToken: String,
    verificationCode: String,
    fbUserId: String,
    isFbUser: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isActive: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    isEmailVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    rememberme: Boolean
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

// Virtual populate
userSchema.virtual("referrals", {
  ref: "referralLinks",
  foreignField: "userId",
  localField: "_id"
});

var User = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
```

And now you can use this route to access referrals from users:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {

  const result = await User.find({}).populate("referrals");

  res.send(result);
});
```

The result will be like this: ( I excluded some fields for simplicity)

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5dd6819201419f5930d02334",
        "name": "User 1",
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "password": "123123",
        "__v": 0,
        "referrals": [
            {
                "_id": "5dd6829831b95a6b2cd58fca",
                "referral_link": "referral_link 1",
                "userId": "5dd6819201419f5930d02334",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dd682a031b95a6b2cd58fcb",
                "referral_link": "referral_link 2",
                "userId": "5dd6819201419f5930d02334",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "id": "5dd6819201419f5930d02334"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd681a101419f5930d02335",
        "name": "User 2",
        "email": "user2@gmail.com",
        "password": "123123",
        "__v": 0,
        "referrals": [
            {
                "_id": "5dd682a731b95a6b2cd58fcc",
                "referral_link": "referral_link 3",
                "userId": "5dd681a101419f5930d02335",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "id": "5dd681a101419f5930d02335"
    }
]
```

UPDATE:

Here is the steps for your project setup:

api.handler.js:

```
exports.findAllUser = async function() {
  console.log("api handler inside");
  let users = await User.find({})
    .populate("referrals")
    .exec();
  console.log("in handler: ", users);
  return users;
};
```

api.controller.js:

```
const handler = require("./api.handler");

exports.getAllUsers = async function(req, res) {
  console.log("userController.getAllUsers");
  try {
    let Users = await handler.findAllUser();
    if (Users) {
      return res.send(Users);
      generateResponse(true, "All Users fetched", Users, res);
    } else {
      generateResponse(false, "No Users found", null, res);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    generateResponse(false, "Error occured, 404 not found!", err, res);
  }
};
```

api.route.js

```
const apiController = require("../controllers/api.controller");
router.get("/",  log, apiController.getAllUsers);
```

Comment: is it necessary to put this `{
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }` in my `User` schema?

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari  yes it must be in the schema. But this is the way to use virtual populate. I tried this code myself, and it is working. Did you try?

Comment: and should i enclosed my all other keys of schema in an object like this `{
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
  }` ?? because see my schema in my question

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari  yes,  also about the previos comment, I tried only with  toJSON: { virtuals: true },  toObject may be removed, but toJSON is required.

Comment: It is saying `User.virtual is not a function`

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari you seem to do something wrong, I updated the answer with full schema code, can you try it with copy paste? And use my route code to test please.

Comment: let me edit the question and include my all code so then you will get an idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202799/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-fahad-hassan-subzwari).

Answer (score 0):

You say  "i don't have 'Referrals' reference _id in Users" so I assume you have a reference to the user in the Referrals schema?

Otherwise, with no way to link them you are lost at sea I'm afraid... :-(

If you do then you would do it in a separate query:

```
const userIds = users.map(user => user._id);

const referrals = await Referrals.find({ userId: { $in: userIds } })
```

The $in operator will grab any field where the user id is included in the array.

EDIT: In response to your update - yes the above should work fine. Then you can do what you want with them e.g. map the referrals to the user objects, or use them individually etc. etc.

EDIT2: Yep this is the way. At this point you have an array of users and an array of referrals so you just need to put them together.

```
users.map(user => ({ 
   // add props from user obj
   ...user, 
   // add all referrals that with matching userId
   referrals: referrals.filter(referral => referral.userId === user._id)
 }))
```

Remember that as you are dealing with asynchronous calls and promises so you will either need to use the async/await keywords, or parse the results in the promise callback.

Comment: see my updated post. I don't think that using your solution i can get the desired results.

Comment: This is what you want - you just need to parse results - i have updated

Comment: "Otherwise, with no way to link them you are lost at sea I'm afraid."  => there is a way called virtual populate, you can check my answer.

Comment: @SuleymanSah - I stated that you cant do it if userId is not defined in the referral. That is correct - you need that field to use virtual populate. I stand by my answer as his Schemas are already written and this shows what is going on under the hood.